# Elasticsearch query like SQL nest query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to query elasticsearch with something like this SQL statement:

```
SELECT *   
FROM EXPENSE.AP_PAYMENTLIST A 
WHERE (ENTRIESID, ID) in (SELECT ENTRIESID, ID 
                          FROM 
                              (SELECT ENTRIESID, MAX(ID) AS ID 
                               FROM EXPENSE.AP_PAYMENTLIST 
                               WHERE ((PAYMENTRETCODE IS NOT NULL OR PAYMENTRETCODE <> '') 
                                      OR STATUS = 'C') 
                                  AND OPERATEDATE >= '2017-06-27 00:00:00' 
                                  AND OPERATEDATE <='2017-07-12 00:00:00'
                               GROUP BY ENTRIESID))   
  AND A.COMPANYCODE = 'ZH00' 
  AND OPERATEDATE >= '2017-06-27 00:00:00' 
  AND OPERATEDATE <= '2017-07-12 00:00:00'
```

How to do it using the Java API?

Comment: You can't just translate a SQL query to elastic query. Elastic Search is not a relational database. What exactly are you trying to do here you SQL seams bad as well. You need to remodel your data and map an index then think about exact queries.

Comment: There is an sql API for Elastic: https://www.elastic.co/products/stack/elasticsearch-sql